# Multimedia keys don't work in Foobar2000 when LibreOffice is in focus (Winamp is not affected)

Tags: windows-7, openoffice, libreoffice, foobar2000, media-keys

Multimedia keys are ignored while focus is on Calc from LibreOffice.

Media keys work in foobar when it's focused, also while other programs are focused.

I use Windows 7 Home Premium SP 1. My Foobar version is 1.3.2.

Media keys are from Lenovo laptop keyboard (g550 model 20023) with standard keyboard driver PS/2, version 6.1.7601.17514.

Multimedia keys work perfectly for Winamp, also while Calc is focused.
With both Foobar2000 and Winamp running only Winamp reacts to multimedia keys.
This problem is considered to be a LibreOffice bug ( https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32664 ) though Winamp found workaround.

I followed instruction from http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Preferences:General:Keyboard_Shortcuts#Multimedia_keys and http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=50067 what fixed some other issues (Winamp seems to have higher priority in receiving keypresses, and it blocked foobar2000 from receiving information that multimedia key was pressed).

Comment: This old bug has never been fixed and no workarounds were ever found. I think you will either have to live with it or use an [alternate free office suite](http://alternativeto.net/software/open-office-suite/) such as Kingsoft Office.

Comment: @harrymc I will probably switch back to Winamp as MP3 player and keep Foobar for MP3 management. I wonder why Winamp works properly - is there some order in which programs receive keypresses?

Comment: There is an order, as the event handlers form a chain and a handler can "eat" the event or pass it on. Libre/OpenOffice probably chains at the beginning and Winamp as well. So invoking the two products at the right order might help (or not).

Comment: @harrymc Is it somehow possible to change this event handler chain? I guess that it requires modification of at least program, but maybe...

Comment: You would need to write a program in C/C++/C# that does global system hooking. See for starters the Microsoft article on [Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @harrymc - I think that your first comment qualifies as answer in this situation.

Comment: Done, although not exactly a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old bug that was reported several times for OpenOffice and LibreOffice :

[Bug 32664: Keyboard volume keys don't work when LibreOffice is in focus](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32664) (2010)
[[Issue] Keyboard volume keys do not work when OOo is open](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14987) (2009)
[[Issue] Multimedia Keys in Windows and Openoffice](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=21087) (2009)
[Issue 99520 – malfunction of multimedia keyboard](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=99520) (2009)

This bug has never been fixed and no workarounds were ever found.

I think you will either have to live with it or use an alternate [free office suite](http://alternativeto.net/software/open-office-suite/)
such as Kingsoft Office.

You have also remarked that Winamp is equally aggressive in taking over these keys,
so it succeeds in taking them back from OpenOffice/LibreOffice.